# Assistance with slow VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This code has taken a couple of hours so far and less than 10% complete, please advise how I can make this faster?

I have tried to explain the code by using comments in the code

Sheet1 has nearly 500k rows on dates, from 1 July 1990 to 30/6/2017 in 30 minute intervals, i.e. 48 rows per day.

I have a table on a different worksheet with a row of 12 columns displaying months 7 to 6, then below the month number in 3 rows are 3 different years

```
Sub Test2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Sheet1 contains the main data set
'Sheet3 contains a table with 12 columns and 3 rows
'Sheet2 is an output sheet
'Sheet4 is an output sheet
'Sheet5 is an output sheet

Dim i As Long 'main sheet rows (Sheet1 473,379 rows)
Dim j As Long 'Columns (Table of dates with 12 columns on sheet3)
Dim LastRowMain As Long 'Last row of sheet 1
Dim LastRowStitch As Long 'Lastrow of the applicable output sheet

Dim Yr As Integer
Dim Mnth As Integer

LastRowMain = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '473,379 rows

j = 3 'First data column in the table

Do Until j = 14

    For i = 4 To LastRowMain

        'Sheet1 column(1) is Date format in 1/2 hour intervasls, i.e. 48 rows per day
        Yr = Year(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1))
        Mnth = Month(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1))

        If Yr = Sheet3.Cells(2, j) And Mnth = Sheet3.Cells(1, j) Then 'If the Date in Sheet1.column(1) matches the date and month in the table, Then
            LastRowStitch = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)).Copy Sheet2.Cells(LastRowStitch + 1, 1) 'Copy that row and put in in to the output sheet below the lastrow
        End If

        If Yr = Sheet3.Cells(3, j) And Mnth = Sheet3.Cells(1, j) Then 'If the Date in Sheet1.column(1) matches the date and month in the table, Then
            LastRowStitch = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)).Copy Sheet4.Cells(LastRowStitch + 1, 1) 'Copy that row and put in in to the output sheet below the lastrow
        End If

        If Yr = Sheet3.Cells(4, j) And Mnth = Sheet3.Cells(1, j) Then 'If the Date in Sheet1.column(1) matches the date and month in the table, Then
            LastRowStitch = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)).Copy Sheet5.Cells(LastRowStitch + 1, 1) 'Copy that row and put in in to the output sheet below the lastrow
        End If

    Next i

Loop 'Go to the next set of dates in the table and loop through the rows again


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: As a minimum all these type  of comparisons If Yr = Sheet3.Cells(2, j) And Mnth = Sheet3.Cells(1, j)    can be done using an array. Looping the array will be faster than the additional overhead of touching the sheet. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx You can use 3 different range variables and Union to combine your copy ranges and paste in one go to each sheet based on your If. You should be able to get Yr and Mnth from initial array as well.

Comment: Thanks QHarr, I will make a copy code and have a play around.  The link you kindly provided looks informative.  Cheers

Comment: Also, you could set `Applcation.EnableEvents` to `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring a bit:

```
Dim YrToCompare2 As Long, YrToCompare4 As Long, YrToCompare5 As Long
Dim MnthToCompare as Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long, LastRow4 As Long, LastRow5 As Long

LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow4 = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow5 = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until j = 14

    MnthToCompare = Sheet3.Cells(1, j)
    YrToCompare2 = Sheet3.Cells(2, j)
    YrToCompare4 = Sheet3.Cells(3, j)
    YrToCompare5 = Sheet3.Cells(4, j)

    For i = 4 To LastRowMain

    'Sheet1 column(1) is Date format in 1/2 hour intervasls, i.e. 48 rows per day
       Yr = Year(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1))
       Mnth = Month(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1))

       If Yr = YrToCompare2 And Mnth = MnthToCompare Then 'If the Date in Sheet1.column(1) matches the date and month in the table, Then
           LastRow2 = LastRow2 + 1
           Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)).Copy Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 1) 'Copy that row and put in in to the output sheet below the lastrow
       End If

       If Yr = YrToCompare4 And Mnth = MnthToCompare Then 'If the Date in Sheet1.column(1) matches the date and month in the table, Then
           LastRow4 = LastRow4 + 1
           Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)).Copy Sheet4.Cells(LastRow4, 1) 'Copy that row and put in in to the output sheet below the lastrow
       End If

       If Yr = YrToCompare5 And Mnth = MnthToCompare Then 'If the Date in Sheet1.column(1) matches the date and month in the table, Then
            LastRow5 = LastRow5 + 1
            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)).Copy Sheet5.Cells(LastRow5, 1) 'Copy that row and put in in to the output sheet below the lastrow
      End If

   Next i

   j = j + 1

Loop 'Go to the next set of dates in the table and loop through the rows again
```

The concept is to reduce VBA - Excel interactions by storing relatively fixed values in variables instead of reading them from Excel 12*500K times, and also counting last rows instead of finding them in every loop. However, you can expect significant improvement by implementing @QHarr's advise on using arrays.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to adjust my code, And also spotting the missing 'j = j + 1' which was also likely sending my code in to an endless loop.  This now took, with Kalapo's comment approx. 2 mins.  Awesome thanks you.  I didn't have time to change into arrays as I need to study this a little more but looking forwards to increasing my understanding of arrays.  Many thansk

Answer (score 1):

Aside from `ScreenUpdating` and `EnableEvents`, you can also set the `Calculation` to manual before running your code. Normally, Excel will automatically recalculate a cell or a range of cells when that cell's or range's precedents have changed.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Then once the loop is done, turn it on again:

```
Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```